# TeX capacity exceeded after switching from ngerman to babel

Tags: pdftex

When I started my thesis, I used package `ngerman`.
After that, I found out that `ngerman` is outdated and `babel` should be used instead.
I changed the package in my document from `\usepackage{ngerman}` to `\usepackage[english]{babel}` as I write the thesis in English language anyway.
When compiling, pdflatex is reporting the following fatal error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \LdfInit\CurrentOption{date\CurrentOption}
```

Line 47 of `english.ldf` is the first line after the coment block:

```
%%
%% This is file `english.ldf',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% english.dtx  (with options: `english,code')
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright 1989-2005 Johannes L. Braams and any individual authors
%%           2013-2017 Javier Bezos, Johannes L. Braams and any individual authors
%% listed elsewhere in this file.  All rights reserved.
%% 
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the Babel system.
%% ---------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is Javier Bezos.
%% 
%% This file may only be distributed together with a copy of the Babel
%% system. You may however distribute the Babel system without
%% such generated files.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the Babel distribution is
%% given in the file `manifest.bbl'. See also `legal.bbl for additional
%% information.
%% 
%% The list of derived (unpacked) files belonging to the distribution
%% and covered by LPPL is defined by the unpacking scripts (with
%% extension .ins) which are part of the distribution.
\ProvidesLanguage{english}
        [2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system]
%% File 'english.dtx'
%% Babel package for LaTeX version 2e
%% Copyright (C) 1989 - 2005
%%           by Johannes Braams, TeXniek
%%           2013-2017 Javier Bezos, Johannes Braams
\LdfInit\CurrentOption{date\CurrentOption}
\ifx\l@english\@undefined
  \ifx\l@UKenglish\@undefined
    \ifx\l@british\@undefined
      \ifx\l@american\@undefined
        \ifx\l@USenglish\@undefined
          \ifx\l@canadian\@undefined
            \ifx\l@australian\@undefined
              \ifx\l@newzealand\@undefined
                \@nopatterns{English}
                \adddialect\l@english0
              \else
                \let\l@english\l@newzealand
              \fi
            \else
              \let\l@english\l@australian
            \fi
          \else
            \let\l@english\l@canadian
          \fi
        \else
          \let\l@english\l@USenglish
        \fi
      \else
        \let\l@english\l@american
      \fi
    \else
      \let\l@english\l@british
    \fi
  \else
    \let\l@english\l@UKenglish
  \fi
\fi
\ifx\l@british\@undefined
...
```

What is the problem with this change from packages ngerman to babel?

UPDATE: The issue comes from the cls file, a derivate of apa6 with changes done at my university. The cls file requires `ngerman` and loads it. When babel is loaded in the preambel it leads to this error.

Comment: you would need to give an example and more of the log, there is not enough information here to help, but do you need babel at all if just using english?

Comment: You have just shown english.ldf v3.3r which is the current version, that file is used in millions of documents without error. Your error is due to code you have not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right, I read through the cls file which my university provides and this cls requires ngerman under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

getting

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<argument> \bbl@tempe
                      USenglish
l.47 \LdfInit\CurrentOption{date\CurrentOption}
```

You *must* remove `\usepackage{ngerman}` from your document. Maybe the loading is hidden in some file you `\input`.

---

A possible workaround for avoiding the dreaded package loaded by the class is to start your document with

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{ngerman}{}
\makeatother

\documentclass[<options>]{<class>}
```

But if the class uses specific features of `ngerman` you're doomed.

Comment: I wished that package would disappear ;-(

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I looked through the cls file from the university, and there ngerman is required. I will stick with ngerman as other things break when I get rid of ngerman like the names for listoftables, listoffigures, ...

Comment: @Joysn What would be the reason for using `ngerman` when the document is in English?

Comment: @Joysn - The `ngerman` package is badly deprecated. Why aren't you using `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}`? `babel` treats the last-listed languare -- here: `english` -- as the main language. If you need German to be the main document language, do run `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: @egreg the class file for the masters thesis is maintained by somebody from university, I already addressed this issue to him. Lets see. The cls file provides some switches where students can change the language, the frontpage etc. and other stuff aligns properly. Unfortunately my TeX knowledge is very bad to replace ngerman by babel reliably.

Comment: @Joysn Tell them that `ngerman` was last updated 25 years ago and some development has been done in the meantime. Plus, `ngerman` has *never* been good for multilingual typesetting and basically supports only German and, partially, English. I added a possible workaround, let's hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error without loading the package "german" or "ngerman":

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\originalTeX}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

The cause of the problem is the definition of `\originalTeX`
in some (older) packages and how it is handled in the Babel core package.

If `\originalTeX` is defined and its definition has a `\selectlanguage` to a default language, Babel will go into an endless expansion loop causing the "input stack" overflow error.

A quick and dirty fix for this problem: Redefine `\originalTeX` to empty, and if "(n)german" or another older package was loaded before call it, i.e.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\originalTeX % reset everything to default langage
\renewcommand{\originalTeX}{}%  avoid babel's endless expansion loop 
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Complete fix has to be done (a) in Babel after deciding how to handle everything when loading the Babel package
and/or (b) in "(n)german.sty" (e.g., just load and use Babel package with german/ngerman option bypassing all the old definitions).